# unable to create Search filter fields in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, controller

[image]

How can i get this kind of layout

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide a bit more details around the issue that you're having? Be more specific.

Comment: are you sure that's not a custom built page?

Comment: I strongly believe that this is a custom VF page/layout.

Answer (score 2):

Although this looks like a Visualforce page, this is actually standard functionality accessible once you have carried out a search.

When you execute a search, you can restrict by object type by clicking on one of the links on the left hand side:

[image]

Once you do this you'll go to a search page with a dropdown on the left hand side. If you click the dropdown you'll see a "filters for all users" option:

[image]

You can choose the fields to filter on:

[image]

Then when you go back to the search page, you can click on the 'Show filters' link:

[image]

and the filters will appear on the page:

[image]